# Apple USB to Ethernet failed to work

Tags: usb, ethernet, kernel-extensions

I bought a USB to Ethernet adapter from Apple, and I downloaded a lot things this afternoon. After dinner, both my retina MacBook Pro and the adapter felt very hot, so I unplugged it. Now the MacBook Pro seems to be frozen and I have to hold the power button for several second to force shut it down. And later that day, the adapter refused to work.

Here is the log in my `/var/log/system.log`:

```
Oct 25 21:38:08 localhost kernel[0]: AppleUSBEthernet: Ethernet address 20:9a:dd:41:24:89
Oct 25 21:38:10 localhost kernel[0]: AppleUSBEthernet::doReenumerateDevice - Link down, Device 4f764100
Oct 25 21:38:10 localhost kernel[0]: ifnet_detach_final: Waiting for IO references on en2 interface to be released
```

Any idea? Is my adapter or the kext is broken?

Answer (score 2):

This can be fixed adding/removing the device from the Network System Preference Pane.